# UIImage drawInRect crops the Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, scaling

I am scaling down an `UIImage` with the following code:

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width * 0.3, image.size.height * 0.3);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSLog(@"Thumb Size %@", NSStringFromCGSize(newSize));
```

It works fine most of the times. But sometimes the image is getting cropped at the bottom. Only the top half is getting rendered. The `NSLog` shows the same size, when the image is rendered right and when it is cropped.

Could someone advice me on this...

Edit: The code works right in Simulators, iPad3 running iOS7. But in iPad2 running iOS6, the problem persists.